# Proof of Rate of convergence for Preconditioned Conjugate Gradient

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, gradient-descent

When reading about [Conjugate Gradient Methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method), one stumbles across [Preconditioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method#The_preconditioned_conjugate_gradient_method). Usually it reads, the Preconditioned Problem:

$$L^{-1}AL^{-T} x = -L^{-1}b$$

where practically, $LL^T \approx A$, converges faster than the non-preconditioned Problem

$$ Ax = -b$$

applying CG. Then you try and read some more and find out, that it has something to do with a [conditioning number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number):

$$\kappa = \frac{|\lambda_{max}(A)|}{|\lambda_{min}(A)|} $$

and if $\kappa$ is close to $1$, CG converges faster. **But Why?**

The closest I've gotten is *Nocedal, Wright: Numerical Optimization (2006), pp. 112-118: Rate of Convergence*, which does not provide a proof, and as a non-mathematician is not very understandable. They basically state, that CG converges faster with clustered eigenvalues of $A$, which would go well with the condition number-idea, i.e. if $\lambda_{max} \approx \lambda_{min}$ are clustered, $\kappa$ is close to $1$.

**Any tip and/or tip on literature would be appreciated. Thanks for the help.**

**Things that are helpful**, but somewhat not satisfying:

- Spectral Analysis (Krylov sequence): [Boyd's Lecture on CG](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/cg.pdf), and thank you @LinAlg [Vandenberghe's lecture on CG](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/cg.pdf) (those two wrote a [book](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=convex+optimization+boyd+vandenberghe&btnG=E) together on Convex Optimization)
- Maybe there exists no proof of some limit of the worst-case convergenz since it is a difficult problem to deal with, and conditioning is more of a "Trial-and-Error"-kinda problem, that depends on the specifics of the case it is used in.

Comment: is http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/cg.pdf helpful?

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks for the suggestion. I will update the question with what I've read. It'd help if it wasn't identical to Boyd's lecture on CG, which you could not have known from the info you had. :( Sorry.